# Calling an undefined array element is showing a value of another defined element

Tags: php, arrays, element, undefined

When calling an undefined element of an array, it is showing me a value of another defined element.

Example of array structure:

```
  $array = array(
    'a' => array(
      'b' => 'c'
    )
  );
```

When using echo command on `$array['a']['b']['x']` it is showing me value of `'c'`. Why this happens I really don't understand since `$array['a']['b']['x']` is not defined.

And then when I try to add another value by using command `$array['a']['b']['x'] = 'y';`
It is rewriting the value of `$array['a']['b']` to `'y'`

Somehow I really don't understand this behaviour, can someone explain how is that possible? And how then I will be able to create a new string value at `$array['a']['b']['x'] = 'xyz'` to not override `$array['a']['b']`?

Comment: you are defining a 2d array, but trying to use it as a 3d array. how do you expect that to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually not related to arrays at all. This is a *string* problem.

In PHP you can [**access and modify** characters of a string with **array notation**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr). Consider this string:

```
$a = 'foo';
```

`$a[0]` gives you the first character (`f`), `$a[1]` the second and so forth.

Assigning a string this way will replace the existing character with the first character of the new string, thus:

```
$a[0] = 'b';
```

results in `$a` being `'boo'`.

Now what you do is passing a *character* `'x'` as index. PHP resolves to the index `0` (passing a *number* in a string, like `'1'`, would work as expected though (i.e. accessing the second character)).

In your case the string only consists of one character (`c`). So calling `$array['a']['b']['x'] = 'y';` is the same as `$array['a']['b'][0] = 'y';` which just changes the character from `c` to `y`.

If you had a longer string, like `'foo'`, `$array['a']['b']['x'] = 'y';` would result in the value of `$array['a']['b']` being `'yoo'`.

---

You cannot assign a new value to `$array['a']['b']` without overwriting it. A variable can only store **one** value. What you can do is to assign an array to `$array['a']['b']` and capture the previous value. E.g. you could do:

```
$array['a']['b'] = array($array['a']['b'], 'x' => 'xyz');
```

which will result in:

```
$array = array(
  'a' => array(
     'b' => array(
        0 => 'c',
       'x' => 'xyz'
     )
  )
);
```

---

**Further reading:**

- [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Very nice and very well written explanation! Thank you a lot! Definitely helped me to get out of the sort of problem I was facing now.